# I'm trying to write a shell command to find and compile all C programs

Tags: linux, shell, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a shell command to find and compile all C programs

```
  find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c 'gcc {} -o $(dirname {})/$(basename {} .c)' \;
```

Is what I have now, and it actually does compile all C files, but it also returns these errors.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm completely stuck and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Probably some of these .c files do not have a main(), so the result is not too surprising, since you're trying to compile and link each one into an executable.

Comment: Show your files' `include` part, maybe here are some errors on dependency.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this unless you know that every .c file is a self-contained executable. Some directories with source files may use a `Makefile` or a `configure` script. What is the problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: Not every file that ends in .c is a program that can be compiled on its own.  C libraries also have this extension and cannot be the sole destination of a complete build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have main defined for your C file/files. Check your individual inclusions as you are trying to create separate executable for each of your C file. You probably want to show your #include of your compiled files.

Comment: That was the problem, you're absolutely right!! thanks so much for the help!